# Return Value in Column B if Column A Contains String

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sample table:

[image]

I am looking for a Google Sheets formula that would match the Name column to "Ben Herbs" and return its corresponding value of 10 into a cell.  Please note I don't want to match exactly to "Ben Herbs 0" because the number is dynamic and will change over time.

How do I do this in Google Sheets formula?

Comment: Within the *Name* Column, there's always going to be just the ***single instance*** of *Ben Herbs* but with a dynamic trailing number?!

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try the `xlookup()` wildcard search:*

```js
=xlookup(<cell_containing_BEN HERBS>&"*",<NAME_column>,<VALUE_column>,,2)
```

example: `=xlookup(D2&"*",A:A,B:B,,2)`

Comment: it worked!  Can you explain the two commas before 2 ... why is that needed?

Comment: Its the **missing_value** parameter: `[OPTIONAL - #N/A by default] The value to return if no match is found`